Only transform tags if child node exists
I have an XML file:
 <body>
     <trans-unit id="Id a" maxwidth="240" size-unit="char">
                <source> original a </source>
                <target>my target value </target>
     </trans-unit>
     <trans-unit id="Id b" maxwidth="240" size-unit="char">
                <source>original b</source>
     </trans-unit>
 </body>


I would like to identity transform the entire document, but only where I have a parent node 'trans-unit' that has a target tag, and one output where I do not:
output 1:
 <body>
     <trans-unit id="Id a" maxwidth="240" size-unit="char">
                <source> original a </source>
                <target>my target value </target>
     </trans-unit>
 </body>


output 2:
 <body>
     <trans-unit id="Id b" maxwidth="240" size-unit="char">
                <source>original b</source>
     </trans-unit>
 </body>


I have looked into identity transformation, but I can't get it to work to either block or include the entire parent node.

Your question is not clear. Do you want the XSL transformation to produce two separate outputs? Which XSLT version does your processor support?

Yes I would like two separate outputs, I am happy if I need to have two separate stylesheets if that makes it easier. The processor can support v3.

For output #1 you can do:
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="trans-unit[target]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

For output #2:
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="trans-unit[not(target)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

You can combine both in a single stylesheet with two separate xsl:result-document instructions (or one principal result and one secondary result).

that has done it, thank you very much

Another common approach for this kind of problem is to use a "filter" pattern:

use an identity template (or in XSLT 3, a "shallow-copy" mode),
provide empty templates to match and filter out any nodes you don't want copied.

To copy only the trans-unit elements which don't have a target:
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:template match="trans-unit[target]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>

To copy only the trans-unit elements which do have a target:
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:template match="trans-unit[not(target)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>

